# How to deal with missing data in this context?

Tags: r, nan, missing-data

I am still quite new to R and was wondering if someone can advise on the best way to deal with missing data with my problem with some health data:

I have a set of data from which I want to work out the class of "AKI", "AKI" was automatically worked out up to a certain point in history. However, anything prior to the cut-off has to be calculated manually.
If the Postop_creat is 1.5 times the Preop_Creat, then it will be a class 1 AKI and if it is 2 times, class 2 and 3 times is class 3, otherwise it is nil.

```
 Preop_Creat Postop_creat AKI
309          90         <NA>   0
310          83         <NA>   0
311          71         <NA>   0
312          79         <NA>   0
313          70           93  NA
314          78           82  NA
```

So, as you can see, I have some rows that already have "AKI" data but without the Postop_creat values and vice versa.

Below is a slightly larger sample with using `dput()`

```
structure(list(Preop_Creat = c(83L, 70L, 75L, 57L, 73L, 78L, 
84L, 129L, 54L, 90L, 83L, 71L, 79L, 70L, 78L, 55L, 57L, 83L, 
110L, 85L, 120L, 97L, 73L, 91L, 64L, 77L), Postop_creat = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50L, 40L, 19L, 
35L, 3L, 8L, 44L, 7L, 47L, 25L, 4L, 32L, 34L), .Label = c("100", 
"101", "106", "107", "109", "113", "115", "116", "118", "123", 
"125", "137", "141", "150", "152", "193", "246", "49", "52", 
"53", "56", "560", "57", "58", "61", "62", "64", "66", "67", 
"68", "70", "72", "74", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", 
"826", "83", "84", "86", "87", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", 
"97", "99", "no data"), class = "factor"), AKI = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 300:325, class = "data.frame")
```

I would be really keen to learn how best to deal with this if I want to write some codes that will populate the "AKI" columns without affecting the pre-existing rows.

Comment: Do you just want to fill the `AKI` column or also get a range or something like that for the missing `Postop_creat`?

Comment: Hello pleas show us what you've tried(your code).

Comment: This is tricky yes, I understand what you mean. 
If you've "NaN" in "AKI" there's no problem as you can compute the class.
But if there "NaN" in "Postop_creat" here it comes.

Comment: What to do when Postop_creat or Preop_creat have NA's? What is postop/preop is, say, between 1.5 and 2? Your question doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: An easy solution for this is that get the indexed of missing values in AKI column, and work with the resulting data frame.

Comment: It is just the AKI column that I need to complete. I've tried some case_when() codes but wasn't sure how to isolate the rows that I wanted without subsetting to a separate df. Now I am thinking perhaps I can write some function to lookup !is.na(Postop_creat) first? (excuse the formatting - using mobile)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following codes and it seems to hold up against doing it on Excel as a check:

```
 aki_manual <- function(pre, post, aki){
  aki <- as.numeric(as.character(aki))
    for (i in 1:length(post)) {
    if(!is.na(post[i])){

      if(post[i]/pre[i] >= 3){
        aki[i] <- "3"
      } else if (post[i]/pre[i] >= 2){
        aki[i] <- "2"
      } else if (post[i]/pre[i] >= 1.5){
        aki[i] <- "1"
      } else {
        aki[i] <- "0"
      }

    } else{
      aki[i] <- aki[i]
    }

  }

  return(aki)
```

Is anyone more experienced than me able to comment or suggest any problem with this approach or an alternative way of doing this? I am eager to learn more.